# Returning a web service response to clients?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jaxb, spring-ws

I am using spring-ws web services and i have  a web service method as below.

what is the difference between the below methods?

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "Request")
@ResponsePayload()
public JAXBElement<Response> getData(@RequestPayload Request request) {

    //Some code
    }
```

and

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "Request")
@ResponsePayload()
public Response getData(@RequestPayload Request request) {

    //Some code
    }
```

To consume this web service by clients which approach is considered good? Do i need to follow first method or second method? **If i directly send jaxb element then will there be any issues to clients**? Which approach is recommended? is it good to return jaxb element directly?

Thanks!

Comment: The difference is in the first the Response is not a XML root object (i.e. annotated with `@XmlRootElement`) and in the latter it is. For the generated message it shouldn't be any different.

Comment: If i directly return JAXBElement then does clients need to do any extra processing to get the result? Thanks!

Comment: Read my response. It doesn't matter for the generated XML! So no there shouldn't be any different, it is XML that gets transfered NOT objects.

Comment: Then client side, to call my web service what kind of return type they can expect?  JAXBElement<Response> response = endpoint.getResult(request)  is it correct? OR Response response = endpoint.getResult(request)  ?

Comment: That depends on the client, the xsd, the transformations. That is not to tell. Not without seeing the xsd. I strongly suggest you read up on XML/SOAP webservices and especially about XML (Un)Marshalling http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazf.html.

Answer (score 0):

Either approach is going to add XML to the body of the SOAP message.  Neither approach has a direct impact on the client.  The client will be based on the XML Schema referenced from your WSDL and not your Java classes.